# create a new environment variable in linux [openwrt]

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I want to use environment variable to save value and after reboot the system, this variable must contain the last value saved
I try this

```
root@OpenWrt:~# BOOTT=1
root@OpenWrt:~# export
export HOME='/root'
export LOGNAME='root'
export PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
export PWD='/root'
export SHELL='/bin/ash'
export SSH_CONNECTION='192.168.1.110 2961 192.168.1.122 22'
export SSH_TTY='/dev/pts/0'
export TERM='xterm'
export USER='root'
root@OpenWrt:~# export BOOTT
root@OpenWrt:~# export
export BOOTT='1'
export HOME='/root'
export LOGNAME='root'
export PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
export PWD='/root'
export SHELL='/bin/ash'
export SSH_CONNECTION='192.168.1.110 2961 192.168.1.122 22'
export SSH_TTY='/dev/pts/0'
export TERM='xterm'
export USER='root'
root@OpenWrt:~#
root@OpenWrt:~# reboot
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

==> after reboot

```
root@OpenWrt:~# export
export HOME='/root'
export LOGNAME='root'
export PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
export PWD='/root'
export SHELL='/bin/ash'
export SSH_CONNECTION='192.168.1.110 3217 192.168.1.122 22'
export SSH_TTY='/dev/pts/0'
export TERM='xterm'
export USER='root'
root@OpenWrt:~# echo $BOOTT
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

so can I obtain env variable which can saved value after reboot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `$HOME/.profile`:

```
BOOTT=1
export BOOTT
```

Comment: root@OpenWrt:~# ls $HOME/.profile 
ls: /root/.profile: No such file or directory
root@OpenWrt:~#

Comment: @stack_A If it doesn't exist, create it!

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to make those variables globally, put them in /etc/profile and source this file in .bashrc of each user.